# How can I logically separate interfaces on a host?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, docker, network-interface

### Problem Introduction

I have a network topology which looks like the below diagram. All hosts are running different Linux distributions, and all my configuration should (hopefully) be done on Host A, which is RHEL7.

[image: Network Topology Graph]

with this routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use 

Iface
default         fw.gatename.    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp34s0
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp9s0
10.0.1.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 bridge1
10.12.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0f1
10.14.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0f0
10.17.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp7s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.2      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 bridge2
172.18.0.3      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 bridge0
172.18.0.4      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 bridge1
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp34s0
192.168.30.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp35s0
192.168.30.91   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 bridge2
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

My main goal is to have each physical interface of Host A map to a Docker container, so that traffic can flow freely ***only*** between both ends of this mapping (and no traffic to or from interfaces outside this mapping).

For example, Container1 should be able to (only) communicate with Host B (along the red links of the diagram), and Container2 should be able to (only) communicate with Host C (along the green links of the diagram).

### An initial attempt

By default, docker creates a bridge `br-97707d67f97c` (for example), which I've removed (because it connects all containers to each other). I created the three bridges (`bridge0`, `bridge1`, `bridge2`), because I thought there might be some hope for some way to make the bridge 'private'.

As it stands right now, I can ping from any container to any interface on Host A, B, or C; I can't ping from one container to another, which I assume is due to them being on the same subnet and confusing the bridge.

### Question

How can I logically separate interfaces on a host so that they can only interact with only the interface(s) I want them to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this error by starting from scratch, then separating my interfaces by subnet.

To use the the diagram in my question as an example, I changed the IP address for Container2 to be within the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet, so 10.0.1.100, for example. I changed the address for Container1 to be on the 192.168.30/24 subnet.

I also removed the IP addresses from `enp35s0` and `enp9s0`, because I considered that these were unnecessary, as the bridges in my example should only operate on OSI Layer 2.